# using multiple select together with $.mobile.urlHistory

Tags: jquery-mobile

within a form I use

```
<select name="vchoice" id="vchoice" multiple data-native-menu="false" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="left">
```

which opens in a new windows as option list is long.

But now using close icon does not work. 
I found out it is because I also have this in use:

```
$(document).on( 'pagebeforecreate', 'body', function () { 
  $.mobile.urlHistory.stack = []; 
  $.mobile.urlstack = []; 
  $( '.ui-page' ).not( '.ui-page-active' ).remove(); 
});
```

Is there a way to use both without problems?

Thanks
Fabian

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: jquery 1.9.1 and jquery mobile 1.3.0